# Microservices: Best Practice for combining data from Instances of SAME service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, microservices

#### Scenario:

We have two instances of the same microservice, which receives two events (pictured as **Event1** and **Event2** below) from Kafka. The instances need to combine the result of their own individual transformations, with that of the other, and send only 1 notification downstream.

I am trying to understand what is the best way to do all this. Specifically, how to make:

- each instance of the microservice to **wait** for the other instance,
- and then **combine** the individual transforms into one
- and then **check** if the other instance has already combined and sent the notification, if yes, then **skip**!

Below diagram to help visualize:

[image: Combining event data in multiple instances of same micro service]

Comment: If the microservice stores the intermediate state in the DB, it can be done.

Comment: Can you point to any existing best practice when a DB is involved?

Comment: This looks like a saga pattern, maybe you could use a processor management service? Basically a simple state machine that kicks off the process instances and coordinate the results, waiting for all before final state which combines and notifies. Of course you need to find a way to correlate your processes so they are known to be part of the same combination at the end. The manager would also be responsible for handling any failures from validation or transformation. Validate, Transform & Combine services send events to the manager to enable it to track state and invoke the next service.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project to implement this. You can code your logic as a simple stateful class that reacts to the events. The idea of Temporal is that the instance of that class is not linked to a specific instance of the service. Each object is unique and identified by a business ID. So all the cross-process coordination is handled by the Temporal runtime.

Here is a sample code using Temporal Java SDK. Go, Typescript/Javascript, PHP, Python are also supported.

```java
  @WorkflowInterface
  public interface CombinerWorkflow {
    @WorkflowMethod
    void combine();

    @SignalMethod
    void event1(Event1 name);

    @SignalMethod
    void event1(Event2 name);
  }

  // Define the workflow implementation which implements the getGreetings workflow method.
  public static class CombinerWorkflowImpl implements CombinerWorkflow {

    private Event1 event1;
    private Event2 event2;
    
    private Notifier notifier = Workflow.newActivityStub(Notifier.class); 
    
    @Override
    public void combine() {
      Workflow.await(()->event1 != null && event2 !=null);
      Event3 result = combine(event1, event2);
      notifier.notify(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void event1(Event1 event) {
      this.event1 = event;
    }

    @Override
    public void event1(Event2 event) {
      this.event2 = event;
    }
  }
```

This code looks too simple as it doesn't talk to persistence. But Temporal ensures that all the data and even threads are durably preserved as long as needed (potentially years). So any infrastructure and process failures will not stop its execution.

Comment: While this looks interesting, I'm concerned about debuggability in the case of a prod issue, not to mention code review when introducing a relatively unheard new library.

Comment: It is the easiest to debug as this code can be replayed under debugger for any production workflow. All events are also recorded into event history, so visibility is perfect. The unheard library is used by companies like Uber, Doordash, Hashicorp, Netflix in production for years. See https://temporal.io/use-cases

Comment: Take a look at this video that I recorded showing how you could debug Temporal workflows: https://youtu.be/fN5bIL7wc5M

Comment: @MaximFateev No Offence meant toward Temporal. Uber and the others are often working on bleeding edge stuff, whereas I work in a Bank, and getting new things approved in code-reviews are a big challenge :( Anyway, I will check out the video, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to get around such kind of *data sync* problems.  But since you are using Kafka, you should be using out of box functionalities offered by Kafka.

**Option 1 (Preferable)**

Kafka guarantees to maintain the order of events **within the same partition**. Therefore if your producer could send these events to the same partition, they would be received by the same consumer *in any given consumer group* (in your case, same instance - or if you are using threads as consumer, same thread of same consumer).  With this you wouldn't need to worry about about syncing events across multiple consumers.

If you are using Spring Boot, this could be easily achieved by providing partition key in [kafka template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html).

More on this topic : [How to maintain message ordering and no message duplication](https://developer.confluent.io/tutorials/message-ordering/kafka.html)

**Option 2**

Now, if you don't have control over producer, you would need to handle this at application side.  You are going to need a distributed caching support, e.g. redis for this.  Simply maintain the boolean state (`completed: true OR false`) for these events and only when all related events are received, process the downstream logic.

***NOTE***:  Assuming you are using a persistence layer, combining and transforming the events should be trivial.  But if you are not using any persistence, then you would need to use in-memory cache for Option1. For Option2, it should be trivial because you already have the distributed cache (and can store whatever you want).

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work, because we are already doing it. Even if Both events come to the same partition, they can get picked by different instances (which are all part of the consumer group).

Comment: In the case of an additional persistence layer, communication with it can involve retries etc, all of which can lead to race condition between two instances

Comment: Both events may not arrive simultaneously. So, when first one arrives in partition, gets picked by instance 1, then 2nd one arrives and gets picked by instance 2

Comment: @Somjit _Even if Both events come to the same partition, they can get picked by different instances_ - this doesn't sound right. Unless a rebalanced is triggered, 1 partition can only talk to 1 consumer of a given consumer group. It's kind of a sticky combination that exists unless a rebalance is triggered. Cardinality between producer and consumers (of a same consumer group) is n:1 not n:n.

Comment: what happens when there is only 1 partition? And Two consumers ? and a Rebalance is triggered in between the events?

Comment: @Somjit Well rebalance would only happen if one of the consumers goes down - which should be a rare-case. For such cases, I imagine you can use some custom logic inside [RebalanceListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.html) and only commit selectively. Or maybe a mixed solution 2 options in the answer together (use distributed caching only for exceptional cases during rebalance).

Answer (score -1):

It's worth noting that you cannot guarantee all of:

- a notification which needs to be sent will be sent in some finite period of time (this is a reasonable working definition of availability in this context)
- no notification will be sent more than once
- either instance can fail or there are arbitrary network delays

Fundamentally you will need each instance to tell the other one that it's claiming responsibility for sending the notification or ask the other instance if it's claimed that responsibility.  If telling, then if it doesn't wait for acknowledgement you cannot guarantee "not more than once".  If you tell and wait for acknowledgement, you cannot guarantee "will be sent in a finite period".  If you ask, you will likewise have to decide whether or not to send in the case of no reply.

You could have the instances use some external referee: this only punts the CAP tradeoff to that referee.  If you choose a CP referee, you will be giving up on guaranteeing a notification will be sent.  If you choose AP, you will be giving up on guaranteeing that no notification gets sent more than once.

You'll have to choose which of those three guarantees you want to weaken; deciding how you weaken will guide your design.